# В чем отличие .Net Standard от .Net Core?

Tags: .net

Не много не понимаю принципиального отличия между .Net Standard и .Net Core.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что .Net Standard это тоже самое, что и .Net Core, но без кроссплатформенности?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как раз таки наоборот, именно .Net Standart является стандартом, для .NET кросплатформенности.
Поясняю, .NET Standart содержит API которые есть в .NET Framework'e, .NET Core, Xamarin. 
.NET Core если не ошибаюсь, поддерживает, только MacOS, Win, Linux. Xamarin MacOS, Android, iOS. А стандарт есть стандарт, и библиотеку можно применять в любом данном приложении.

К примеру, имеет некоторый интерфейс, допустим IList, соответсвенно данный интерфейс или его реализация есть в .NET Core, Xamarin, .NET Framework.
Или к примеру возьмем DirectoryInfo/Directory. Как мы все прекрасно знает, в разных системах, свои понятия о директории, скажем, тот же путь или расширение файла. Но благодаря .NET Standart, мы можем писать приложения по работе с директориями и файлам в тех режимах, которые поддерживают все платформы.

Так что .NET Core включает в себя .NET Standart.

Принимайте его просто за перечень API которые есть на всех платформах, на которых можно писать на C# (наверное и на F#/VB.NET).

Answer (score 3):

- `NET Standard` - это **спецификация**. При этом, если у нас есть библиотека, которая собрана под какую то определенную версию NET Standard, то она может быть использована в различных реализациях NET Standard (как спецификации).
- Это не очень технически точно, но NET Standard можно воспринимать как "интерфейс", в то время как разные фреймворки являются его реализацией.

Вот диаграмма, которая показывает это концепцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Таким образом если вы создаете NET Core библиотеку, то она не является частью NET Standard  и не может быть использована в таких его реализациях, как Xamarin или NetFramework. Просто за счет того, что NET Core содержит набор API, которые отсутствуют в спецификации NET Standard.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard это спецификация/стандарт/договор для реализации(implementing) BCL (Base Class Library)

.NET Standard относится к .NET как HTML спецификация относится к браузеру. Браузер -- это реализация HTML спецификации.

> или как интерфейс к классу. Интерфейс, ведь, тоже спецификация для класса.

То есть

- .NET Core
- .NET Framework
- Xamarin

каждый из них является имплементацией .NET Standard.

информация взята отсюда: https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/dotnet-core-standard-difference